# Augmenting variable argument list

Tags: variadic-functions

Is there a way for a function to append to variable number of arguments it already received? I'm using `__builtin_va*` of libgcc for ARM to implement variable argument functions (`typedef`'ed appropriately)

```
int wrapper(char *name, ...)
{
  ...
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, name);
  another_function(name, args);
  va_end(args);
  ...
}
...
void another_function(char *name, va_list p)
{
}
```

Since `another_function` has no way of detecting the end of arguments, I want to pass `NULL` as the last argument. Is there anything that can be done in `wrapper` to have `NULL` accessible in `another_function` using `va_list` pointer `p`?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html